# android.app.Activity and android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

When I start an android project in eclipse, instead of `android.app.Activity` in the `MainActivity.java` file, it uses `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity`.
So I have lots of problems, because it seems not to be included in my libraries.
I prefer to start with `android.app.Activity` in automatic project start. Could you please guide me?
Thanks

Comment: instead of app-compat library use android.jar file

Comment: Just add support library related to it. Also just move to Android Studio for develop your projects

Comment: Why are you still working on eclipse for android project? You can migrate to android studio.